# VBA: Multiplying by a fraction within a loop

Tags: vba, excel

My code works below works but I'd like to add one function.  I've got a large data sheet with each line repeated three times.  Within each set of three I've added a month twice.  The purpose is to smooth out forecasted sales into one month and two months beyond the estimated shipping date.  Now I'd like to multiply my the values in column E by factors into column F.  The original line in each set of three will `=50%*E:E`  in column F, the second line will have `=30%*E:E` in column F, and the third line will have `=20%*E:E` in Column F.   This process should be repeated continually for every set of three lines. Problem: My current code does give me the correct value, however the values are two cells lower than they need to be. Thanks for any help in advance! My current code is below:

```
Public Sub DateAdd()

Dim r As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim Quant As Long
Dim dttTemp As Date
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SalesForce Projects")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For r = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
With ws.Cells(r, 1).EntireRow
    .Copy
    .Resize(2).Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
End With
dttTemp = ws.Cells(r, "S").Value
ws.Cells(r + 1, "S").Value = DateSerial(Year(dttTemp), Month(dttTemp) + 1, 
Day(dttTemp))
ws.Cells(r + 2, "S").Value = DateSerial(Year(dttTemp), Month(dttTemp) + 2, 
Day(dttTemp))
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

' This is where my code is bad

```
For l = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -3

Quant = ws.Cells(l, "E").Value
ws.Cells(l, "F").Value = Cells(l, "E") * 0.5
ws.Cells(l + 1, "F").Value = Cells(l, "E") * 0.3
ws.Cells(l + 2, "F").Value = Cells(l, "E") * 0.2
Next l

End Sub
```

Comment: Am I correct, that you need just weighted moving average in column F? You can insert formula.

Comment: Not weighted moving average but a fraction of the total.  Pretend there are 90 rows on the sheet, and each set of 3 rows represents a set, so 30 sets.  I'd like the first row of every set to be 50% of the value in column E, the second row of every set to be 30% of the value in column E, and the last row in every set to be 20% of the value in column E.  I need a loop that will repeat this process for a massive spreadsheet

Comment: The thing is that you have not even **made an attempt** to accomplish your goal in your current code. You are asking **us to do your work for you**. SO is not a code for me site. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more.

Comment: Scott, my apologies. I'm relatively new to VBA, as well as posting on StackOverflow, and have very little experience working with loops.  I'll write some code to accomplish the goal and then update my question

Comment: Scott I've updated the code. It works but the values are two cells lower than where I need them to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it in the first loop like below?

```
Public Sub DateAdd()

Dim r As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim Quant As Long
Dim dttTemp As Date
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SalesForce Projects")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For r = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
With ws.Cells(r, 1).EntireRow
    .Copy
    .Resize(2).Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
End With
dttTemp = ws.Cells(r, "S").Value
ws.Cells(r, "F").Value = Cells(r, "E") * 0.5        '\\ First line
ws.Cells(r + 1, "S").Value = DateSerial(Year(dttTemp), Month(dttTemp) + 1, Day(dttTemp))
ws.Cells(r + 1, "F").Value = Cells(r, "E") * 0.3    '\\ Second line
ws.Cells(r + 2, "S").Value = DateSerial(Year(dttTemp), Month(dttTemp) + 2, Day(dttTemp))
ws.Cells(r + 2, "F").Value = Cells(r, "E") * 0.2    '\\ Third line
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for and worked perfectly

Comment: How would you adjust your code to avoid the first line (I'd prefer to have titles in the first)?  Thank you

Comment: I am not sure I understood your requirement. What do you mean by "titles"? How do you want them to be handled?

Comment: In the first row of each column, their are titles (not quantities and dates).  For example: Cell A1 = "Customer", Cell B1 = "Quantity", Cell C1 = "Shipping Date"

Comment: Ah, so you don't want to repeat first few columns in two rows that are being inserted. Can you explain column layout and the columns you don't want to repeat?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "50% of the value in column E," you could mean the entire value of all 90 in column E or just the value of the three cells in a set. If you mean the first then (I assume that row 1 is headings, so your values start at row 2.) In cell F2 enter the formula

```
 =Sum(E:E)*.5
```

In cell F3 enter

```
 =SUM(E:E)*.3
```

In cell F4 enter

```
=SUM(E:E)*.2
```

If you mean the other option then enter:

```
In F2   =Sum(E2:E4)*.5
in F3  =Sum(E2:E4)*.3
In F4   =Sum(E2:e4)*.2
```

Now select f2:f4. Place your mouse on the bottom right corner and you should see the cursor change to a small black cross. Double-click and the formulas will be replicated down the sheet. If you have more than one sheet to fill then control click on the tab names before starting this process to similtainoiusly copy to all selected sheets.

Comment: Yes, I mean the second option. However you would not sum the total, just the value of E in that column. And then the process would repeat: In F5   =E5*.5
in F6  =E6*.3
In F7   =E7*.2

Answer (score 0):

In this case there is no need to loop backwards. Update the `For` statement to the following:

```
For l = 1 to ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 3
```

Then it should produce desired results.

Comment: Thank you.  When I changed my code to this, I got "Compile Error: Expected end of statement"

Comment: I figured it out, the "To 1" at the end must be removed